# How to prove using contrapositive on $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, if $a$ is even, then $a$ does not divide $2a^2+a+7$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification

I've tried to prove it in contrapositive $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ ($\neg$($a$ does not divide $2a^2+a+7$) $\rightarrow$ $\neg (a$ is a even number)), which basically means that if a divide the equation then a is an odd number. So:

$a$ is odd: $a = 2k+1$ for an arbitrary positive integer k.

$2(2k+1)^2+(2k+1)+1 = (2k+1)x$, since if $a$ can divide the equation, there must be another integer x such that $ax=2a^2+a+7$

But i don't know what to do next or even I'm on the right track.

Comment: If $a$ is even, then $2a^2+a+7$ is odd; but an even number can’t divide an odd number, or else $2$ would divide an odd number — a contradiction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to assume that $a$ divides $2a^2+a+7 = a(2a+1)+7$. From this you should see that $a$ must divide $7$. Can you finish?

Comment: I'm still confuse on how to approach the answer from that

Comment: Do any even numbers divide $7$?

Comment: Ohh I see, since there is no even number divide 7, therefore if a is even, it can't divide $2a^2+a+1$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: It might help to phrase the contrapositive a little more understandably: if $a$ does divide $2a^2+a+7$, then $a$ is odd. Now what does it mean to say that $a$ divides $2a^2+a+7$? It means that there is an integer $n$ such that $2a^2+a+7=an$. And

$$2a^2+a+7=a(2a+1)+7\,,$$

so $a(2a+1)+7=an$. What does this tell you about $7$?

Comment: Is that mean $a$ must divide 7?

Comment: @YZY: Yes, it does: $7=an-a(2a+1)=a(n-2a-1)$.